# QRawFont::fromFont not working correctly

Tags: macos, qt

I found something wrong on Qt on Mac OS X 10.6.3:

```
QFont font = QFont("Wingdings");    //font.family() == "Wingdings"
QRawFont rawFont = QRawFont::fromFont(font);    //rawFont.familyName() == "Lucida Grande"
```

I think rawFont.familyName() should be "Wingdings".
On Windows this code works correctly.

I tried this method:

```
QRawFont ( const QString & fileName, qreal pixelSize, QFont::HintingPreference hintingPreference = QFont::PreferDefaultHinting )
```

on a font file and it works correctly.

I really don't know how  to correct this.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *may* have spotted a bug.

If you look at the [4.8 implementation of QRawFont::fromFont](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/text/qrawfont.cpp#line628), you'll see this:

```
[...]
#if defined(Q_WS_MAC)   
    QTextLayout layout(QFontDatabase::writingSystemSample(writingSystem), font);
    layout.beginLayout();
    QTextLine line = layout.createLine();
    layout.endLayout();
    QList<QGlyphRun> list = layout.glyphRuns();
    if (list.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            rawFont = list.at(i).rawFont();
            if (rawFont.familyName() == font.family())
                return rawFont;
        }
        return list.at(0).rawFont();
    }
#else
[...]
```

Clearly this method is a hack on Mac OS X. The method changes in the HEAD revision (presumably 5.x) and no longer has a hack for OS X.

Comment: I'm trying to setRawFont to a GlyphRun, but with above code, the result was wrong on Mac
Is there any way to set a font from QFontComboBox into a GlyphRun on Mac?